# Maximising borderless form covers task bar only when maximised from a normal size

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I am using C# to give an application 'fullscreen mode' using borderless form and maximise method.
This works perfectly when i am making the form borderless while it is not maximised - all you can see on the screen is the form, taskbar is covered.. However, if i maximise the form manually (user interaction), and then attempt to make it borderless & maximised, the task bar is drawn over the form (as i am not using WorkingArea, part of the controls on the form are hidden. It is the intended behaviour to NOT show the taskbar).
I tried setting the form's property TopMost to true, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there any way to rework this to always cover the taskbar?

```
if (this.FormBorderStyle != System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None)
    {        
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    }
    else
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    }
    if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.FormBorderStyle == System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable)  this.WindowState=FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if i maximise the form manually (user interaction)...

The issue is that your window is already internally marked as being in the maximized state.  So maximizing it *again* will not change the current size of the form.  Which will leave the taskbar exposed.  You'll need to restore it first back to Normal, then back to Maximized.  Yes, that flickers a bit.

```
    private void ToggleStateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (this.FormBorderStyle == FormBorderStyle.None) {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        else {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is happening, and i *hate* app's that assume they can take all of my screen. While this might be acceptable for 1024x768 displays, my 30" display is wasted when the damn thing decides it owns my screen.

So my message is, maybe focus on making sure all of your **controls are visible** rather than focusing on maximizing the window.

You can always detect window size changes and then override the default behavior, taking care of the unexpected issue you are encountering. But rather than maximizing and taking all of a 30" display, calculate how large the window needs to be and set the size accordingly.

My 2 cents, which is precisely what my thoughts are worth ;)

Comment: John, the app being developed is not a public application, the production environment is expected to disable the taskbar altogether; however, for the purpose of purity i would like to verify that my app can handle Windows with taskbar enabled. Further to that, this specific scenario is being used to make VMR9 renderer fullscreen. You would agree that watching some video is more pleasant when you don't have that taskbar there?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the WinApi SetWindowPos method, like this:

```
public static class WinApi
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, 
                                    int x, int y, int width, int height, 
                                    uint flags);

    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

    public static void SetFormTopMost(Form form)
    {
        SetWindowPos(form.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                     SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
}
```

In your form call it like this:

```
WinApi.SetFormTopMost(this);
```